# linux bash - move x percentage of files from each folder

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, copy, move

I have the following folder structure:

```
maindir
|-sub1
|-sub2
|-sub...
|-sub1000
```

What I want to achieve is to move from each sub directory eg. 10% of the files which each folder contain into a new folder maindir2 with the same structure:

```
maindir2
|-sub1
|-sub2
|-sub...
|-sub1000
```

Assuming in the sub directories from maindir is the following amount of files (numbers in bracelets):

```
maindir
|-sub1 (10)
|-sub2 (100)
|-sub...
|-sub1000 (50)
```

I would like to have as output the following in maindir2:

```
maindir
|-sub1 (1)
|-sub2 (10)
|-sub...
|-sub1000 (5)
```

and in maindir:

```
maindir
|-sub1 (99)
|-sub2 (90)
|-sub...
|-sub1000 (45)
```

Please let me know how this is possible with a bash command preferably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible ;)

it look ugly (one line) but work,
run it from inside of maindir:

```
find . -type f -exec dirname {} + | uniq -c | while read n d;do echo "Directory:$d Files:$n Moving first:$(($n / 10))";mkdir -p ../maindir2${d:1};find $d -type f | head -n $(($n / 10)) | while read file;do mv $file ../maindir2${d:1}/;done;done
```

Regards,

Comment: thank you so much! that is exactly what I was looking for. works like a charm!